# How to check if two columns are logically the same in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe as below:

| column_1 | column_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | car |
| 2 | truck |
| 1 | car |
| 3 | plane |
| 3 | plane |
| 2 | truck |

You can clearly see that the `column_1` is logically describing the same thing as the `column_2`. But my dataset is huge and I can't use a visual inspection to understand this relationship between these 2 columns. How can I check if two columns (as shown in the example) are actually logically the same?

Comment: Do you mean that every object in column 2 always have the same value? `car` always has value 1?

Comment: @Guy yes, car always has the value 1, truck has 2 and plane has 3...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) and compare both output arrays by `all` for test if all values are `True`s:

```
print (pd.factorize(df['column_1'])[0] == pd.factorize(df['column_2'])[0]).all()
True
```

Another idea with mapping:

```
d = df.set_index('column_1')['column_2'].to_dict()
print (df['column_1'].map(d).eq(df['column_2']).all())
```